# How to convert object type to integer type for Nearest Neighbor function?

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I'm working with a 10 x 2304 (on Spyder) and I need to run the NearestNeighbor function on it. Under the variable explorer, it states that my array is of the object type and its value is "ndarray object of numpy value" (I don't even know what that is supposed to mean). When I print the first lines this is what I get:

```
>>> print(X)

[array([0, 2, 4, ..., 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint8)
 array([209, 209, 209, ..., 166, 149,  80], dtype=uint8)
 array([161, 159, 167, ..., 192, 186, 194], dtype=uint8)
 array([ 49,  48,  30, ..., 169, 197, 222], dtype=uint8)
 array([175, 173, 165, ...,  95, 153,  77], dtype=uint8)
 array([ 98, 100,  98, ..., 244, 244, 246], dtype=uint8)
 array([ 98,  99,  98, ..., 214, 221, 223], dtype=uint8)
 array([158, 165, 179, ...,  36,  34,  33], dtype=uint8)
 array([177, 168, 166, ..., 185, 183, 178], dtype=uint8)
 array([ 46,  45,  50, ..., 240, 237, 246], dtype=uint8)]
```

When I pass the array as an argument for the nearest neighbor function I get this error:

```
>>> nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=3, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(X)
>>> _, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(X)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I've read that this is what happens when the shape of the input array isn't a (generalised) "box" that can be turned into a multidimensional array. I find this odd considering what I am working with but I figure it might be because of the fact that my array is not a normal "array of arrays" as I would like.

When I do this:

```
new_X = []
for i in range(10):
    new_X.append(X[i])
new_X = np.array(new_X)
print(new_X)
```

this is my result:

```
[[  0   2   4 ...   1   1   1]
 [209 209 209 ... 166 149  80]
 [161 159 167 ... 192 186 194]
 ...
 [158 165 179 ...  36  34  33]
 [177 168 166 ... 185 183 178]
 [ 46  45  50 ... 240 237 246]]
```

Also note that in the variable explorer it states that `new_X` is of the `unit8` type and it is clearly an array of arrays.

```
>>> nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=3, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(new_X)
>>> _, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(new_X)
>>> print(indices)
[[0 1 3]
 [1 7 2]
 [2 1 3]
 [3 6 8]
 [4 5 8]
 [5 9 4]
 [6 3 8]
 [7 1 0]
 [8 6 3]
 [9 5 6]]
```

So as you can see I get the result I'm looking for, but the problem is I am trying to optimize my code. I want to be able to run the `NearestNeighbor` function on `X` without having to do the manipulation that I did in the for loop. Is there any way I can convert my `X` array to the form and type that I want without the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ndarray object of numpy value` is a way to say that your python list is encapsulated in a numpy object called `ndarray` which stands for n-dimensional array.

In your case, you have a `list` of `ndarray`s. To get a list of list, you can use the `tolist()` method:

```
X = [i.tolist() for i in X]
```